# How to run python script in windows

Tags: python, windows

I need to write a python code which enables me to verify whether the received SSL certificate from a website is valid or not. the code snippet is gonna be executed in windows platform.
I've been using Editra to code python recently which is equipped with PyStudio plugin. I got confused if it's a possible idea or not.
Does anyone have any idea how to make it work?

Comment: So... what's your question again?

Comment: What is the better way to implement a snippet of code in windows to parse, extract and check validity of SSL certificates provided by websites?
Does this make sense at all?

Comment: May I suggest you edit your question to be more like your comment, and your question title to mention SSL and websites... It'll get picked up more easily and would be less ambiguous

Answer (score 3):

If you want to distribute a Python script on Windows, (which doesn't have Python installed by default), you can use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/). `py2exe` converts your Python script into an executable that Windows users can run *without* them needing to install Python.

Comment: Cool - I didn't know this one.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Python XY](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) if you are concerned about a good Python installation under windows including a lot of helpful, preconfigured packages.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's just a plain script you want to execute, you can do so by invoking the python runtime in the command line, and issuing it to execute the script.

For instance:

```
python myscript.py
```